Compressing row and column problem for tables in html
I am writing html code for the given table. I don't know why the row gets compressed for 2nd row. What am I doing wrong here?
Please help me on this.
enter image description here
I am trying this code and was expecting this:
enter image description here

Welcome on Stackoverflow! When posting a question you can increase your chances of getting a meaningful reply if you share your actual code (in form of a working snippet). Screenshots can only be looked at but will make it difficult for us to reproduce your problem.

Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please do not use printscrens of code. If possible write it in your question so we can help you.
